# How to set login to phpmyadmin for default user/password in wamp server?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

I understand that I need to log in to wamp server in order to create a database.  My problem is that the phpmyadmin page opens without asking me to log in.  So, I presume that I am not logged in.  If so, I do not know how to log out.  I know this is so basic but I am stuck here.  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You can follow this link to get idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498343/putting-a-password-to-a-user-in-phpmyadmin-in-wamp

Comment: Check this step-by-step tutorial: http://phpform.net/password-for-phpmyadmin-in-wamp-server.php

Answer (score 7):

The default username is "root"
default password is '' (empty/blank).

if u want to know the password
go to wamp installation path\apps\
for example C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin2.10.1
in this path u can fine the file named 'config.inc.php'
open that file with any text editor and search for
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']
the password had been stored in this variable.

Also check out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420894/wamp-server-mysql-user-id-and-password

Comment: Thanks but I know the username and password but I do not get anywhere to use it.  There is no link to log out.  It does not ask to log in.  Where can I log in or out?  Chaski

Comment: Try opening the index.php file e.g.: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin-3.5.8-english/index.php

Comment: if you are presumably logged in, then click on "Databases" tab inside phpMyAdmin, then type in a name for your database and click "Create".

Comment: Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Wamp Directory on your window and check phpmyadmin in apps folder inside wamp.

`D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14`

Open **`config.inc.php`** and go on line 28.

Just put new password or remove it as per your need:

> /* **Authentication type** */
>
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
> //$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
> $**cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']** = '';

Comment: Welcome on super user. Remember that to go to a new line (without leaving a line empty in the middle) you have to add 2 spaces at the `end of the line.  `. <-- In this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set username and password for wamp server it never asked for it.

Answer (score 0):

What I can also recommend is downloading the latest phpMyAdmin from http://www.phpmyadmin.net.
Then unzip the folder to C:\wamp\phpMyAdmin-4.1.3-all-languages
Then launch

```
    [http://localhost/phpMyAdmin-4.1.3-all-languages/index.php](http://localhost/phpMyAdmin-4.1.3-all-languages/index.php)
   now it should only ask you for username (root) and password (blank/none/empty)
```

Comment: I was given the option to log on again after no activity for a certain period of time.  I also copied these files as you suggested and now that problem is solved.  Thanks for your help.  Chaski

Comment: Pleasure! please mark my answer as answered :-)